# Google visualization table doesn't understand my code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here, i'm literally banging my head of the table!, the data is coming off in the html source, but the page is just blank, the google table doesn't seem to like it.

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'COND_CODE');
    data.addColumn('number', 'PEICE_NO');
    data.addRows([
    <?php
                while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                    extract($row);


      echo "{['$COND_CODE'],  ['$PEICE_NO'],"; } ?>
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
  }
</script>
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is the html output

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'COND_CODE');
        data.addColumn('number', 'PEICE_NO');
        data.addRows([
        {['BTH'],  ['03084'],{['BTH'],  ['03084'],{['TC'],  ['02549'],{['SM'],  ['03049'],{['BTH'],        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: can you please show the resulting html also? Post i to http://pastebin.com/ and attach a link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
data.addRows(
<?php
    $rows = array();
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
        extract($row);
        $rows[] = array($COND_CODE, $PEICE_NO);
    }
    echo json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
);
```

The should output your data in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong syntax for a DataTable.

try doing this instead:

```
 echo "['$COND_CODE', '$PEICE_NO' ],"; } ?>
```

Comment: Just tried this, still getting no visual table, any ideas?

Comment: The generated html should look like this: `data.addRows([ ['BTH', '03084'], ['BTH', '03084'] ]);` Adjust your code to get that syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "{['$COND_CODE'],  ['$PEICE_NO']},";?>
```

Seeyour syntax is wrrong